# When a user clicks on an image, run a JS function but also post the value to php script

Tags: php

I'm wondering if there is a way within my code where a user can click on an image, but on that click take the value of it and send via a post request to PHP code. For example at present I have this:

```
<div class="grid-2 dashboardIcons">
    <h3 class="fontAmaticH1">Mindfulness</h3>
    <a class="cursor" onclick="toggleWindow()"><img value="6" src="images/Mindfulness.png"></a>
</div>
```

Would I have to wrap this in a form tag like the below?

```
<form method="post">
    <a class="cursor" onclick="toggleWindow()"><img value="6" name="module" src="images/Mindfulness.png"></a>
</form>
```

My PHP code will then just take that value and do something with it:

```
<?php
 // I need to get the value from the clicking on an image
    if(isset($_POST['module']))
{
 //Do something
}
?>
```

Any help what so ever would be much appreciated!

Comment: Use AJAX for this. https://learn.jquery.com/ajax/

Comment: @user3783243 Hi, I wouldn't be sure on how do to this, is that an easier way of getting a value and parsing it to php code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `jQuery` you can do something like this...

```
function toggleWindow() {
    $("#theForm").ajaxSubmit({url: 'server.php', type: 'post'})
}
```

Comment: Hi, will this get the value thats saved please i.e: `value="6"`?

Comment: add this line `<input type="hidden" value="6">` after `<form method="post">
` than it will pass 6 to `server.php`

Comment: Can I ask, in which bit do I say the page I need to pass the value too? `x-page.php` and do I need to add in a `submit` somewhere in order to activate the post request?

Comment: not `submit` button is not necessary   `<input type="hidden" value="6">` inside `<form method="post">` and `</form>` tag

Answer (score -4):

For this you can use AJAX where you can execute your JavaScript code using onclick event. In your JavaScript write down an AJAX script at the end so that it will execute the php code after execution of your JavaScript code.

Comment: Hi, welcome on stackoverflow. Please post as answer only answers with full explanations and code. You may refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer to learn how to write a good anser.